# AWK pattern match results wrong

Tags: awk

I have the below command

```
$ awk -v p=502013514208295320210301 '-F"' '$6==p' inputfile.txt
```

The input file contains the below lines

```
"2021-03-01"|"AUTO"|"50310040379713492021022120210321"|"PPU_ROAM_BELL_CORPORATE_US"|"PPU"|"302610024660748"|"4037971349"|"2021-02-21"|"2021-02-21"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"1024"|"2.8945"|"MB"|"ACTIVE"|"20210301110305"
"2021-03-01"|"AUTO"|"50310040343788162021022120210321"|"PPU_ROAM_BELL_CORPORATE_US"|"PPU"|"302610024660773"|"4034378816"|"2021-02-21"|"2021-02-21"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"1024"|"2.8682"|"MB"|"ACTIVE"|"20210301110306"
"2021-03-01"|"AUTO"|"50309964761428982021030120210324"|"PPU_ROAM_BELL_CONSUMER"|"PPU"|"302610033244797"|"6476142898"|"2021-03-01"|"2021-03-01"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"98"|"98"|"CAD"|"ACTIVE"|"20210301060312"
"2021-03-01"|"AUTO"|"502007418564386720210219"|"CORP_US_7GB_CAP"|"SOC"|"302610024671577"|"4185643867"|"2021-02-19"|"2021-02-19"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"7168"|"5.0508"|"MB"|"ACTIVE"|"20210301110312"
"2021-03-01"|"AUTO"|"50310040382948922021022120210321"|"PPU_ROAM_BELL_CORPORATE_US"|"PPU"|"302610024670673"|"4038294892"|"2021-02-21"|"2021-02-21"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"1024"|"3.0488"|"MB"|"ACTIVE"|"20210301110336"
"2021-03-01"|"AUTO"|"502013514208295320210201"|"CORP_EXCLUSION_LIST_US_25GB"|"SOC"|"302610017663970"|"5142082953"|"2021-02-01"|"2021-02-01"|"2021-03-01"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"25600"|"322.834"|"MB"|"EXPIRED"|"20210301120317"
"2021-03-01"|"AUTO"|"50310090530187832021020920210309"|"PPU_ROAM_BELL_CORPORATE_US"|"PPU"|"302610023679066"|"9053018783"|"2021-02-09"|"2021-02-09"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"1024"|"6.5195"|"MB"|"ACTIVE"|"20210301070346"
"2021-03-01"|"AUTO"|"502013514208295320210301"|"CORP_EXCLUSION_LIST_US_25GB"|"SOC"|"302610017663970"|"5142082953"|"2021-03-01"|"2021-03-01"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"25600"|"18.0635"|"MB"|"ACTIVE"|"20210301110311"
"2021-03-01"|"AUTO"|"50310090530140952021020920210309"|"PPU_ROAM_BELL_CORPORATE_US"|"PPU"|"302610024354632"|"9053014095"|"2021-02-09"|"2021-02-09"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"1024"|"6.3232"|"MB"|"ACTIVE"|"20210301090332"
"2021-03-01"|"AUTO"|"502013514208295320210301"|"CORP_EXCLUSION_LIST_US_25GB"|"SOC"|"302610017663970"|"5142082953"|"2021-03-01"|"2021-03-01"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"25600"|"18.0635"|"MB"|"ACTIVE"|"20210301110311"
"2021-03-01"|"AUTO"|"502013514208295320210301"|"CORP_EXCLUSION_LIST_US_25GB"|"SOC"|"302610017663970"|"5142082953"|"2021-03-01"|"2021-03-01"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"25600"|"18.0635"|"MB"|"ACTIVE"|"20210301110311"
"2021-03-01"|"AUTO"|"50310040354297052021022120210321"|"PPU_ROAM_BELL_CORPORATE_US"|"PPU"|"302610024661575"|"4035429705"|"2021-02-21"|"2021-02-21"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"1024"|"2.9463"|"MB"|"ACTIVE"|"20210301110355"
```

The current output is as shown below.

```
    "2021-03-01"|"AUTO"|"502013514208295320210201"|"CORP_EXCLUSION_LIST_US_25GB"|"SOC"|"302610017663970"|"5142082953"|"2021-02-01"|"2021-02-01"|"2021-03-01"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"25600"|"322.834"|"MB"|"EXPIRED"|"20210301120317"
    "2021-03-01"|"AUTO"|"502013514208295320210301"|"CORP_EXCLUSION_LIST_US_25GB"|"SOC"|"302610017663970"|"5142082953"|"2021-03-01"|"2021-03-01"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"25600"|"18.0635"|"MB"|"ACTIVE"|"20210301110311"
    "2021-03-01"|"AUTO"|"502013514208295320210301"|"CORP_EXCLUSION_LIST_US_25GB"|"SOC"|"302610017663970"|"5142082953"|"2021-03-01"|"2021-03-01"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"25600"|"18.0635"|"MB"|"ACTIVE"|"20210301110311"
    "2021-03-01"|"AUTO"|"502013514208295320210301"|"CORP_EXCLUSION_LIST_US_25GB"|"SOC"|"302610017663970"|"5142082953"|"2021-03-01"|"2021-03-01"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"25600"|"18.0635"|"MB"|"ACTIVE"|"20210301110311"
```

Why `502013514208295320210201` is showing in awk result since I am only searching for `502013514208295320210301`. I need to print only results with `502013514208295320210301`

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples only, could you please try following. Tested and written in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -M -F'"\\|"'  -v p="502013514208295320210301" '$3==p'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simply making field separator as `"|"` for all the lines of Input_file. creating variable `p=502013514208295320210201` and then in main section checking condition if 3rd field is equal to p if yes then printing that line. Why your comparison is not working, your numbers are too large for awk to understand, so with GNU `awk`'s `-M` option we can handle this.

Answer (score 1):

You might use string comparison in this case (fact values are enclosed `"` suggest that they are supposed to be strings) to avoid problems with excessively big numbers. Let `file.txt` content be

```
"2021-03-01"|"AUTO"|"50310040379713492021022120210321"|"PPU_ROAM_BELL_CORPORATE_US"|"PPU"|"302610024660748"|"4037971349"|"2021-02-21"|"2021-02-21"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"1024"|"2.8945"|"MB"|"ACTIVE"|"20210301110305"
"2021-03-01"|"AUTO"|"50310040343788162021022120210321"|"PPU_ROAM_BELL_CORPORATE_US"|"PPU"|"302610024660773"|"4034378816"|"2021-02-21"|"2021-02-21"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"1024"|"2.8682"|"MB"|"ACTIVE"|"20210301110306"
"2021-03-01"|"AUTO"|"50309964761428982021030120210324"|"PPU_ROAM_BELL_CONSUMER"|"PPU"|"302610033244797"|"6476142898"|"2021-03-01"|"2021-03-01"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"98"|"98"|"CAD"|"ACTIVE"|"20210301060312"
"2021-03-01"|"AUTO"|"502007418564386720210219"|"CORP_US_7GB_CAP"|"SOC"|"302610024671577"|"4185643867"|"2021-02-19"|"2021-02-19"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"7168"|"5.0508"|"MB"|"ACTIVE"|"20210301110312"
"2021-03-01"|"AUTO"|"50310040382948922021022120210321"|"PPU_ROAM_BELL_CORPORATE_US"|"PPU"|"302610024670673"|"4038294892"|"2021-02-21"|"2021-02-21"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"1024"|"3.0488"|"MB"|"ACTIVE"|"20210301110336"
"2021-03-01"|"AUTO"|"502013514208295320210201"|"CORP_EXCLUSION_LIST_US_25GB"|"SOC"|"302610017663970"|"5142082953"|"2021-02-01"|"2021-02-01"|"2021-03-01"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"25600"|"322.834"|"MB"|"EXPIRED"|"20210301120317"
"2021-03-01"|"AUTO"|"50310090530187832021020920210309"|"PPU_ROAM_BELL_CORPORATE_US"|"PPU"|"302610023679066"|"9053018783"|"2021-02-09"|"2021-02-09"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"1024"|"6.5195"|"MB"|"ACTIVE"|"20210301070346"
"2021-03-01"|"AUTO"|"502013514208295320210301"|"CORP_EXCLUSION_LIST_US_25GB"|"SOC"|"302610017663970"|"5142082953"|"2021-03-01"|"2021-03-01"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"25600"|"18.0635"|"MB"|"ACTIVE"|"20210301110311"
"2021-03-01"|"AUTO"|"50310090530140952021020920210309"|"PPU_ROAM_BELL_CORPORATE_US"|"PPU"|"302610024354632"|"9053014095"|"2021-02-09"|"2021-02-09"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"1024"|"6.3232"|"MB"|"ACTIVE"|"20210301090332"
"2021-03-01"|"AUTO"|"502013514208295320210301"|"CORP_EXCLUSION_LIST_US_25GB"|"SOC"|"302610017663970"|"5142082953"|"2021-03-01"|"2021-03-01"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"25600"|"18.0635"|"MB"|"ACTIVE"|"20210301110311"
"2021-03-01"|"AUTO"|"502013514208295320210301"|"CORP_EXCLUSION_LIST_US_25GB"|"SOC"|"302610017663970"|"5142082953"|"2021-03-01"|"2021-03-01"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"25600"|"18.0635"|"MB"|"ACTIVE"|"20210301110311"
"2021-03-01"|"AUTO"|"50310040354297052021022120210321"|"PPU_ROAM_BELL_CORPORATE_US"|"PPU"|"302610024661575"|"4035429705"|"2021-02-21"|"2021-02-21"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"1024"|"2.9463"|"MB"|"ACTIVE"|"20210301110355"
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\""}($6=="502013514208295320210301"){print}' file.txt
```

output

```
"2021-03-01"|"AUTO"|"502013514208295320210301"|"CORP_EXCLUSION_LIST_US_25GB"|"SOC"|"302610017663970"|"5142082953"|"2021-03-01"|"2021-03-01"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"25600"|"18.0635"|"MB"|"ACTIVE"|"20210301110311"
"2021-03-01"|"AUTO"|"502013514208295320210301"|"CORP_EXCLUSION_LIST_US_25GB"|"SOC"|"302610017663970"|"5142082953"|"2021-03-01"|"2021-03-01"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"25600"|"18.0635"|"MB"|"ACTIVE"|"20210301110311"
"2021-03-01"|"AUTO"|"502013514208295320210301"|"CORP_EXCLUSION_LIST_US_25GB"|"SOC"|"302610017663970"|"5142082953"|"2021-03-01"|"2021-03-01"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"NOT AVAILABLE"|"25600"|"18.0635"|"MB"|"ACTIVE"|"20210301110311"
```

Comment: It did not work when I use it with variable